# Derivative of a vector with respect to a matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, tensors

let $W$ be a $n\times m$ matrix and $\textbf{x}$ be a $m\times1$ vector. How do we calculate the following then?

$$\frac{dW\textbf{x}}{dW}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That totally depends on definition being used.

Comment: Also, I like your thinking, just make it explicit as what the definition should be.

Comment: The wiki had "?" for this type of Matrix differentiation. "Result of differentiating various kinds of aggregates with other kinds of aggregates" in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Other_matrix_derivatives. I encountered this in the context of neural networks and not sure either how it's defined.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The quantity in question  is a $3^{rd}$ order tensor.

One approach is to use index notation
$$\eqalign{
  f_i &= W_{ij} x_j \cr\cr
 \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial W_{mn}}
 &= \frac{\partial W_{ij}}{\partial W_{mn}} \,x_j \cr
 &= \delta_{im}\delta_{jn} \,x_j \cr
 &= \delta_{im}\,x_n \cr
}$$
Another approach is vectorization
$$\eqalign{
  f &= W\,x \cr
    &= I\,W\,x \cr
    &= (x^T\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(W) \cr
    &= (x^T\otimes I)\,w \cr\cr
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial w} &= (x^T\otimes I) \cr
}$$

Comment: Are you missing any $\sum_{}{}$ symbol?

Comment: @arindammitra I guess lynn uses some Einstein summation notaion in the exrpression of $f_i$

Comment: I don't think the rewriting of f is correct. At least it doesn't produce the same result when I try on a small example.

Comment: I think the order of your $\mathbf{I}$ and $\mathbf{x}^T$ should be changed.

Comment: @Sandi Your edits to lynn's answer are wrong. The correct vectorization formula is $${\rm vec}(IWx)=(x^T\otimes I){\rm vec}(W)$$ Please read the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products). This question must be cursed. The accepted answer is (still) wrong, and (now) lynn's answer has been corrupted.

Comment: Can someone plz fix this? In the answer, I thought that vectorization assumes vectorization by columns, like @greg suggested in his correction, but the current answer uses vectorization by rows and it is not mentioned explicitly!

Answer (score 7):

While it's true that the true answer is a 3rd degree tensors, in the context of (Feed-Forward)NN, taking this gradient as part of the chain rule where you have a final output that is a scalar loss, the calculations can simplify enormously - and be represented as an **outer product**, where $\frac{d\textbf{x}W}{dW} = \textbf{x}^T \cdot \_\_$

Specifically, if $L$ is the loss, and $z=\textbf{x}W+b$ (or $\textbf{a}W+b$ for any downstream "inputs"/activations), where $\textbf{x}$ (or $\textbf{a}$) are **row** vectors, then:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial W} =\frac{\partial L}{\partial z} \frac{\partial (\textbf{x}W+b)}{\partial W} = \textbf{x}^T\cdot\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}
$$

I'm in the process of making a YouTube video with more explanation. Will update this as soon as it get's published.

EDIT: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4RNPJD-IkQ&ab_channel=MeerkatStatistics) is the video, the related part starts at 09:00

Comment: Thanks for the explanation in your video. Makes things clear on why most neural net literature writes the derivative $\partial z/\partial W$ as $\mathbf x^T$. However, I am trying to calculate the Hessian by applying the second order chain rule. That involves computing $(\partial z/\partial W)^2$, should it be $(\mathbf x^2)^T$ or $\mathbf{xx}^T$?

Comment: Great video, by the way!!

Answer (score -14):

**For independent case:**

If $\mathbf{x}$ is independent of $W$, this problem can be calculated as follows.

$$\cfrac{\partial W\mathbf{x}}{\partial W}=
\cfrac{\partial}{\partial W}
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{11} & w_{12} & \cdots & w_{1m} \\
w_{21} & w_{22} & \cdots & w_{2m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
w_{n1} & w_{n2} & \cdots & w_{nm} 
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}
$$

$$
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cfrac{\partial w_{11}}{\partial w_{11}} & \cfrac{\partial w_{12}}{\partial w_{12}} & \cdots & \cfrac{\partial w_{1m}}{\partial w_{1m}} \\
\cfrac{\partial w_{21}}{\partial w_{21}} & \cfrac{\partial w_{22}}{\partial w_{22}} & \cdots & \cfrac{\partial w_{2m}}{\partial w_{2m}} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\cfrac{\partial w_{n1}}{\partial w_{n1}} & \cfrac{\partial w_{n2}}{\partial w_{n2}} & \cdots & \cfrac{\partial w_{nm}}{\partial w_{nm}} 
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}
$$

Therefore, all elements are $1$. Eventually, the result is below.

$$
\cfrac{\partial W\mathbf{x}}{\partial W}=
(\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{1_{m}}) \mathbf{1_{n}}
$$

Then $\mathbf{1_{k}} \in \mathbf{R}^{k}$ is

$$\mathbf{1_{k}}=[1 \ 1 \ \cdots 1]^{\text{T}}$$

**For dependent case:**

If $\mathbf{x}$ is dependent of $W$, it is more difficult than independent case. Likewise,

$$
\cfrac{\partial W\mathbf{x}}{\partial W}=
(\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{1_{m}}) \mathbf{1_{n}} +
W \cfrac{\partial F(W) }{ \partial W}\mathbf{x}_{0}
$$

Then, $\mathbf{x}$ can be replaced as follows

$$\mathbf{x}=F(W)\mathbf{x}_{0}$$

where, $F(W) \in \mathbf{R}^{m \times n}$ is a matrix function, for which parameters are $W$, and $\mathbf{x}_{0} \in \mathbf{R}^{m}$ is independent of $W$.

Comment: Hi,  can you please point me to a book where I can learn more about derivatives w.r.t matrix?

Comment: This may be the accepted answer, but it's just plain wrong. The problem is that the gradient $$\frac{\partial W}{\partial W} \ne 1_n1_m^T$$ as asserted. It is instead a 4th order tensor which can be written in index notation as $$\frac{\partial W_{ij}}{\partial W_{kl}}=\delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jl}$$

Comment: I fully agree with @greg. This answer is simply **plain wrong**... I am a bit scared to see that it has 4 upvotes...