# Derivative and $2$nd derivative of $f(\beta) = \sum_i^n \ln(1+e^{\beta^T \textbf{x}_i})$

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to find the derivative of the following function:
$$ f(\beta) = \textbf{1}^Th(X\beta) = \sum_i^n \ln(1+e^{\beta^T \textbf{x}_i}) \\h(t) = \ln(1+e^t) 
$$
Where $\beta$ is a $(p,1)$ vector, $X$ is a $(n,p)$ vector, and $h(X\beta)$ is the element wise use of the function $h(t)$, i.e. it is a $(n,1)$ vector.

I want to find $\nabla_{\beta}f$, and $\nabla^2_{\beta}f$.

This is easy if I ignore the summation, do this per element wise, and then add it in the end. But I was wondering if there's a way to do this **strictly** in matrix notation?

The results should come out $X^T \sigma(X\beta)$ (where $\sigma$ is the element-wise sigmoid function) and $X^T \Sigma X$, where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with $\sigma(X\beta)(1-\sigma(X\beta))$  as it's diagonal.

I think this is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3300843/342736), only instead of differentiating w.r.t. $A$, it's w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098910/gradient-and-hessian-of-sum-i-log-left1-exp-left-t-i-leftwt-x-i-ri

Answer (score 2):

Given a scalar $\chi$ variable, a function $\phi=\phi(\chi)$, and its derivative
$\phi' = \frac{d\phi}{d\chi},\;$ the differential is easy to calculate
$$d\phi=\phi'\,d\chi$$
But when these functions are applied element-wise to a vector $x$ (or matrix $X$)
argument, the differential expression requires a Hadamard product
$$\eqalign{
&f = \phi(x) \qquad
&f' = \phi'(x) \qquad
&df = f'\odot dx \\
&F = \phi(X) \qquad
&F' = \phi'(X) \qquad
&dF = F'\odot dX \\
}$$
In this problem, the derivatives of the function involve the logistic function $\sigma(\chi)$:
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \log(1+e^\chi)
,\qquad \phi'&=\sigma
,\qquad \phi''&=\sigma' = (1-\sigma)\,\sigma
}$$
Define the vectors
$$\eqalign{
w &= X\beta     &\quad\implies dw = X\,d\beta \\
h &= \phi(w) \\
h' &= \sigma(w) &\quad\implies dh = h'\odot dw \\
}$$
Write the objective function then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\psi &= {\tt1}^Th \\
d\psi &= {\tt1}^Tdh \\
 &= {\tt1}^T(h'\odot dw) \\
 &= dw^Th' \\
 &= (d\beta^TX^T)h' \\
 &= (X^Th')^T d\beta \\
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\beta} &= X^Th' \;\doteq\; X^T\sigma(X\beta) \\
}$$
For the next part, it will be convenient to rename $\,h'=s,\,$ i.e.
$$\eqalign{
s &= \sigma(w)\qquad&s'=({\tt1}-s)\odot s\qquad &ds = s'\odot dw \\
S &= {\rm Diag}(s) &s' = (I-S)s &ds = (S-S^2)\,dw \\
}$$
NB: Replacing Hadamard products with diagonal matrices is a useful trick.

Now calculate the differential and gradient of the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 g &= X^Ts \\
 &= X^Tds \\
 &= X^T(S-S^2)\,dw \\
 &= X^T(S-S^2)(X\,d\beta) \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial \beta}
 &= X^T(S-S^2)X \\
}$$
The gradient of the gradient is the Hessian.
Note that it's symmetric, as one would expect.